# Nested tuple spread distributivity

Tags: typescript

Today I bumped into this:

```js
type Test = [...[1]|[3], 2]
//   ^? type Test = [1, 2] | [3, 2]
```

What is this? Is it documented anywhere?

If I do this instead I get the expected behaviour:

```js
type Test = [...[1|3], 2]
//   ^? type Test = [1 | 3, 2]
```

I'm not looking for a solution here but rather to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed documented. See the [Variadic tuple types PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094):

> When the type argument for `T` is a union type, the union is spread over the tuple type. For example, `[A, ...T, B]` instantiated with `X | Y | Z` as the type argument for T yields a union of instantiations of `[A, ...T, B]` with `X`, `Y` and `Z` as the type argument for `T` respectively.

Your second example does not distribute because the type of the spread element is not a union, but rather a tuple containing a union as its first element.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```js
type Test = [...[]|[1][3,4,5], 2];

// which is equivalent to
type Test = [2] | [1,2] | [3,4,5,2];
```

Your example is just a special case where both of the tuples you spread have just a single item. Where `[1,2]|[3,2]` happen to be equivalent to `[1|3, 2]`. But even with two tuples of length 2 the results can be very different:

```js
type Test = [...[1,2]|[3,4], 5];
// results in 
type Test = [1,2,5] | [3,4,5];

// and is not the same as
type NotTest = [1|3, 2|4, 5];
// because that means:
type NotTest = [1,2,5] | [1,4,5] | [1,3,5] | [1,4,5];
```